# How do I make a polygon in Google Maps that covers the world?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to make a polygon that covers the world, and has a second Path so that a shape is cut out of it.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the correct lat/lng values to use, and the 'inside polygon' is filled in, instead of being punched out.  Any ideas?  I'm using the Google Maps 3 javascript API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a kml file that covers the world except Virginia](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=37.155939&lng=-79.497071&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/virginia_inverted_kml.xml)

```
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs> <!-- covers the whole world -->
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
180,85 90,85 0,85 -90,85 -180,85 -180,0 -180,-85 -90,-85 0,-85 90,-85 180,-85 180,0 180,85
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
<innerBoundaryIs>  <!-- hole -->
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>-75.914,36.576,0.0 ...
```

To have the 'inside polygon' not filled, its path has to wind in the opposite direction as the outside path.  I have a [winding calculator](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/Polygon_with_holesA.xml) that works on kml, and a page that [helps reverse the winding of polygons from kml](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/crues_450_windingFix_kml.xml) (not very user friendly)